# 'undefined NaN' when changing view or month

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, fullcalendar

I'm following [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/craigcav/uKCbX/) of how to bind a jQuery fullCalendar with knockout.js:

The issue is that the calendar displays `'undefined NaN'` when any of the buttons are clicked. Any ideas??

I thought maybe fullCalendar is having problems rebinding on click due to the modelView:

```
    myModel.calendarViewModel = new ko.fullCalendar.viewModel({
        events: myModel.items,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        viewDate: myModel.viewDate
    })
```

Comment: So I commented out this line: //$(element).fullCalendar('gotoDate', ko.utils.unwrapObservable(viewModel.viewDate)); within ko.bindingHandlers.fullCalendar.update and it fixed the issue. Must have been a clash with fullCalendar setting the initial day and the knockout binding handler.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the following code "viewDate: myModel.viewDate" below editable:true is causing the issue. Please try removing it and check. Just let me know whether my suggestion works out.

```
  myModel.calendarViewModel = new ko.fullCalendar.viewModel({
    events: myModel.items,
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true

})
```

Check this link [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yuvaraj_b/uKCbX/67/)